# Sources to know about latest research

Tags: research

I wanted to keep myself aware of the latest research news and trends etc. in economics. What are some good sources (newsletters, magazines, websites etc.) for that?

I did find one from Nature. How comprehensive is it? If it is not that comprehensive, what sources shall I read from to have a comprehensive summary of latest developments?

Comment: "Economics" is very broad in this sense. There are DSGE models, Game Theory, Industrial Organization, Transportation Economics, Econometrics, Political Economy, Monetary Policy, Neuroeconomics, etc. It is unlikely that you can follow the latest research in all these fields. Could you narrow your interest?

Comment: "I did find one from Nature. How comprehensive is it?" This part is unclear. Are you asking how good the magazine Nature is as a source for reading the latest research?

Comment: Well there are general purpose journals like journal of economic perspectives or American economic review, but as @Giskard pointed out given how broad economic research nowadays is even professional economists can’t keep up with every single subfield. Also, Nature does not even have economics listed as a subject it’s just subset in social sciences or business and industry and number of articles from social sciences there is relatively low - hence I am guessing that’s not the best place to keep up with research in economics

Comment: @1muflon1 https://www.nature.com/subjects/economics

Comment: @Giskard oh I was actually looking at this: https://www.nature.com/nature/browse-subjects here the Econ is not listed

Comment: It’s weird that they have it listed as a subject in one place and not in another

Comment: @Giskard I was talking about this https://www.nature.com/subjects/economics It says latest research and reviews. And I probably overestimated what I would be able to cover. I would want to focus for now not on very specific or specialized sub-disciplines, are there magazines or stuff that summarize or bring together interesting and important bits from different subdisciplines?

Comment: @1muflon1 I get your point, are there magazines or stuff that bring together or say pool together interesting and important stuff from different sources? I mean Journal of The economic perspectives for instance would cover only articles submitted to them, but are there sites or magazines that summarize developments, from not necessarily including very specialized fields but general ones?

Answer (score 2):

The National Bureau of Economic Research is a good source for the latest in economic research: https://nber.org/

You can also go to Brookings institute:  https://www.brookings.edu/

Federal Reserve Board:  https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres.htm